# Java: Solidity solcJ-all and etheriumJ - unable to add dependency

Tags: java, dependencies, solidity

I need to run solidity compiler from Java. For that purpose I've found [solcJ](https://github.com/ether-camp/solcJ) and [ethereumj](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj). But unfortunately, I'm unable to add
the dependency `org.ethereum solcJ-all 0.4.23` into my maven project.

Maven fails with the following message:

> Failed to execute goal on project h: Could not resolve dependencies
>   for project gg:h:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find
>   org.ethereum:solcJ-all:pom:0.4.23 in
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.

The same issue happens for [all other versions of solcJ](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ethereum/solcJ-all).

Has somebody faced the same issue?

Comment: I think you need to add bintray to the repository list.

Comment: go to .m2 folder and delete all existing jars of solcJ, then rebuild project with `$mvn clean install` or any build tool you are using

Comment: Thanks! Adding bintray repo helped.